# How to retrieve Unicode text from Notepad file saved as ANSI text file

Tags: unicode, ansi, notepad

I accidentally saved a file written in Greek as ANSI instead of Unicode. I had so much stuff written there, notes for my upcoming college exams and I really really need them. Now everything is ''???''

Is there a way to retrieve the file?

Answer (score 1):

The data has been lost. Characters that your system's ANSI charset does not support were converted to `?`, and you can't undo that. There is no recovering characters that were converted to `?`.

Notepad should have warned you about the data loss before it allowed the file to be saved.

[image: save prompt]